# Android SQLite getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm having a problem when using the Cursors to perform a SQLite query to an Android database, if I try to use getPage I get an `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`
error, am I doing something wrong with the cursors? doing a cursor.getColumnCount() gets 4 that's correct, and there's a row, so that's not the problem, what could be causing the error? Thanks in advance

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pagesManager";

// Pages table name
private static final String TABLE_PAGES = "pages";
// Pages Table Columns names
private static final String PAGES_KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String PAGES_KEY_NAME = "pageName";
private static final String PAGES_KEY_DATE = "lastDate";
private static final String PAGES_KEY_PAGE = "pageUrl";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PAGES + "("
            + PAGES_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + PAGES_KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+ PAGES_KEY_DATE + 
            " TEXT," + PAGES_KEY_PAGE + " TEXT" +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PAGES_TABLE);
}

   public PageListItem getPage(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PAGES, new String[] { PAGES_KEY_ID, PAGES_KEY_NAME, PAGES_KEY_DATE, PAGES_KEY_PAGE }, PAGES_KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            System.out.println("Cursor no es nulo");
        }
    PageListItem page = new PageListItem(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    cursor.close();
    return page;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a wrong id, so the getPage() couldn't find it.

Comment: You should accept this answer in order to close the question :)

Comment: I can't, it says I need to wait for 2 days, thanks for the reminder anyway